# UIButton action with multiple argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios6, uibutton

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Objective C: Sending arguments to a method called by a UIButton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4844146/objective-c-sending-arguments-to-a-method-called-by-a-uibutton)

i have a problem with `uibutton` action. I want send argument when the button clicked. i saw some examples that work with tag prop. and the class is id sender. but i dont want to fixed it. the action goes to my own manager. how can i do ?

```
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(goToSubViewManager:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

here is the gotosubviewmng

```
- (void)goToSubViewManager:(ViewType*)vTipi
{


}
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what you want to do: when UIButton detects an open arg in it's action, it sends itself through, which is why so much code uses `(id)sender`.  Even explicitly stating that you will accept only objects of type ViewType is not a deterrent, you'll simply get a UIButton instance passed through to your method.

Comment: change - (void)goToSubViewManager:(ViewType*)vTipi to - (void)goToSubViewManager:(id)sender.

Comment: i want to send two parameter when the button clicked. if i fill only fill tag properties, it will performed too slow.

Answer (score 1):

you should only use `- (void)goToSubViewManager:(id)sender`. or `- (void)goToSubViewManager`

so here are 2 ways to solve your problem.

1. you can use variables or property.

> > ```
> > - (void)yourMethod
> >
> >     {
> >         //your code
> >         _vTipi = yourVTipi;
> >     }
> > ```
>
> ```
> - (void)goToSubViewManager
> {
>     //here you can use _vTipi;
> }
> ```

1. you can add a Category for the UIButton , to add an id type property(such as @property(nonatomic) vTipi).faking instance variables for UIButton.(how to do you can look at this : http://oleb.net/blog/2011/05/faking-ivars-in-objc-categories-with-associative-references/) Then you can use like this:

> ```
> - (void)goToSubViewManager:(id)sender
> {
>     //you can user ((UIButton *)sender).vTipi
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Use can use **tag** property of the button. And then can use that object by comparing the tag assigned.

```
UIButton* rightButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeDetailDisclosure];
    [rightButton addTarget:self
                    action:@selector(goToSubViewManager:)
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
rightButton.tag=1;
//
```

then in the call back you can compare it as

```
- (void)goToSubViewManager:(id)sender
{
     if(sender.tag==1){
// you can use an array of that object(if multiple), then apply your logic
}

}
```

Comment: but i dont want to fix with property of tag. i wrote that. any idea ?

Comment: @EmreEkşioğlu then you can declare it as a global variable in .h, ViewType* vTipi, and you can use it when button is clicked..